# Increased APK size just by upgrading RN version?

Tags: android, react-native

I've just upgraded my RN project from React Native version 0.57.8 to 0.58.0.

The differences can be found [here](https://github.com/pvinis/rn-diff-purge/compare/version/0.57.8..version/0.58.0). Now what I noticed is that my Android APK size increased from 16~17 to 23~24 mb. Wondering if anyone facing the similar issues while upgrading RN version?

And in what way can we go about it?

**UPDATES:**
Not sure if it's related but I saw this statement

> Task :app:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForRelease
>   Unable to strip library '/myApp/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/mergeJniLibs/release/0/lib/armeabi/libicu_common.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI'. Packaging it as is.

Comment: I noticed a jump similar to that but I also added several large dependencies around the same time. So it couldn't say for sure which one caused it. Also the changes that you listed are just the changes that occur in the code we access, there are more changes that take place inside `react-native` in the *node_modules*. If you look at the actual [changes](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/compare/v0.57.8...v0.58.0) there are over 1000 commits with over 3000 file changes

Comment: @Andrew: Yes I do understand the real deal is within `node_modules`. However I really don't expect there's a jump of 7MB..

Comment: Just out of curiosity I built two APKs one with `0.57.8` and one with `0.58.0` just to see if there was any difference in a vanilla app. `0.57.8` came in at  **7.9MB** and the `0.58.0` came in at **15.7MB**. It is actually closer to **8MB** in difference between the versions!! There is also a substantial difference between the size of the *react-native* folder in *node_modules* too. `0.57.8` is **18.7MB** while `0.58.0` is **38.3MB**. There has clearly been a lot added .

Comment: @Andrew: Ahhh never thought of checking that way. Good point, means its essential for `0.58.0` and nothing gone wrong with my upgrading process..

Comment: Also for curiosity I built the recent `0.59.0` release and it comes out at **28.8MB**, and the *react-native* folder in *node_modules* is **43.5MB**